# MediaBox style pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, popup

I asked a similar question last week asking about window pop-ups. I've thought of a possible alternative to window pop-ups and that's mediabox/lighbox style pop-ups.

Is it possible to have a link that you click on and it opens a mediabox type window to the side. (Possibly a window you can drag around within the page) Then you click another link and it opens another window, you can then have "pop-ups" without having pop-ups. You can then view the two pop-up windows at the same time and compare them. They need to stay open until the user closes them, meaning if the person navigates around the page the window will stay where they dragged it.

Does that make sense? I understand this isn't the best way of doing this, but is this possible using a plugin? I do not have the JavaScript skills to create this. So does anyone know of anything out there that does this, or is easily customizable into doing this?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: so you want multiple popups per page or a popup from a popup?

Comment: if a user were to navigate away from that page, the popups would then dissapear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). Put the "lightbox" content into a hidden div. Then do:

```
$("#divId").dialog({
    position: ['left', 'top']
});
```

Similarly for the other div. You'll generally want to pass more [options](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#options) to customize behavior of the dialog, but that's the basics